# Python exponential plot is wrong

Tags: python-3.x

I am new using python and try to do some plots. I realized, that a plot of a bump function is incorrect. I have no idea how python came to this result.

This is my 'code'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MainBody():
x = np.linspace(0.0001,99.9999,1000)

result = np.exp((-1.0)/(x*(100.0-x)))

plt.plot(x,result)       
plt.show()
```

I got this result
[image]

but I should get this
[image]

I know that Python is powerful but I think such simple things should work without occuring such errors, where is my mistake?

Thank you

Matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `plt.ylim` to set the y-limits. Otherwise, by default, matplotlib will try to show the entire dataset, whose y-limits go roughly from 0 to 1:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.0001,99.9999,1000)
result = np.exp((-1.0)/(x*(100.0-x)))
plt.plot(x,result)       
plt.ylim(0.9975, 0.9999)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello unutbu, thank you for your anser and explanation. Now it is clear what is gonig on.